# Error in android studio import non-android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-bootstrap

I am new to Android Studio. When I import a non Android Studio project, it shows this error. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
 > Project
 > Task-Reminder-App-master:C:\Users\XXXX\AndroidStudioProjects\XX\Task-Reminder-App-master\project.properties:
 > Library reference
 > ..\..\Downloads\Android-Bootstrap-master\AndroidBootstrap could not be
 > found Path is
 > C:\Users\XXXX\AndroidStudioProjects\XX\Task-Reminder-App-master\..\..\Downloads\Android-Bootstrap-master\AndroidBootstrap
 > which resolves to
 > C:\Users\XXXX\AndroidStudioProjects\Downloads\Android-Bootstrap-master\AndroidBootstrap
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a library reference within the `project.properties` file that you need to edit yourself and remove.

You can add that back to the project at a later point, or you could probably just use a proper Gradle dependency if that's this library.

https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap